# how can I turn a generator into a list?

Tags: sage

I am performing a mathematical function on a list of numbers, however I'm getting the result as a generator instead of another list.

I have tried putting the 'for' loop first but it gives me typeMonoidElement

```
ciphertext =  ([((G**block)*([choice(list(range(n)))]**n))%(n**2)] for block in blocks)
```

I expected the output to be a list of numbers but im getting a generator instead.

Comment: Just a quick hint - if you could tell us what `block` is in your code, that would be quite helpful.  Nonetheless your question should be fairly answerable, and I will attempt to do so momentarily.

Comment: As kcrisman says in the answer, you could do `ciphertext = [...]` instead of `ciphertext = (...)` to get a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `block` is, but in general a lot of Python stuff does now return generators instead of lists.  I just made up something to complete your example.

```
blocks = [1,2,24,5]
ciphertext =  ([((G**block)*([choice(list(range(n)))]**n))%(n**2)] for block in blocks)
cipher text
```

This returns `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fcf3c5403c0>` or the like.  Actually, this is a feature!  Now you don't have to hold the entire list in memory, and can iterate over it whenever you find it convenient.

However, if you want a list, you can do it in two ways.

- `list(cipher text)`
- `[block^2 for block in blocks]`

You used parentheses rather than brackets (in American English usage); the parens makes a generator.  Hope this helps.

---

On a separate note, your code needs a lot of extra stuff to work.  The generator I just created doesn't notice that `G` is undefined, and that `n` is currently a function, not an integer!  This is a simpler example of the same thing.

```
blocks = [1,2,24,5]
ciphertext =  (block^2 for block in blocks)
print ciphertext
list(cipher text)

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fcf3c540410>
[1, 4, 576, 25]
```

Also note you are allowed in Sage to do `x^2` rather than `x**2`.  Enjoy Sage!

Comment: the list() function was exactly what I needed here, thank you! I know it needed a few extra things to work, I ws trying to follow the "minimal amount of code to explain your point" rule.

Comment: I guess there are two philosophies on that, the "minimal to explain point" and the "minimal for someone to actually get it to (not) work".  I think that on this forum the latter is the default expectation, but that might not be the case on all help sites.  Anyway, glad it helped - enjoy your lists, generators, and Sage!